# Android custom Search View

Tags: java, android

im using the FloatingSearchView by Arlib, and i have a problem which i dont know how to resolve.
The problem is that i need to remove the tint of my searchbar after clicking on it i want to make the background non changed.
This is how it look:
[image]

And after click:

[image]

And i want to make this background not changed to the gray one...
How i can make it?
Im trying to change the theme but doesnt help..

Answer (score 0):

Seems the dim can't be changed in that library: https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/issues/233

Comment: Shiet.. Do you know another library, that allows me to make the floating search bar below menu name?
I mean i want something looking like this:

SOME MENU VALUE /n
[ searchbar ]